# Join two tables without relationship, add 1 to many

Tags: sql

I've been frequenting this site for awhile now but this time, I didn't find any answers around this question so here goes.

I have two tables that do not have any PK/FK or relationship otherwise. What I am trying to do is the following.

Table 1

```
Column A
A
B
C
```

Table 2

```
Column B
1
2
3
```

Desired Result:

Combined Table

```
Column A         Column B
A                1  
A                2
A                3
B                1
B                2
B                3
C                1
C                2
C                3
```

Pretty much, for every value in the first table, append the full list of the second table until there's no more.

I hope this makes sense on what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `cross join`:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
ORDER BY ColumnA;
```

Comment: Wow, that was an exceptionally fast response. Thank you! Also, I feel very silly right now. :'D

Comment: You are very welcome. I appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in other answers, you'll want to use `CROSS JOIN` which will give you the Cartesian product of the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB
  FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2;
```

You might see this expressed in older code like this:

```
SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB
  FROM t1, t2;
```

"Cartesian product" is a term from mathematics: the Cartesian product of two sets X and Y (tables in relational databases are actually sets) is the set of all ordered pairs (x,y) where x in X and y in Y. In your case you are getting the Cartesian product of the sets `all values of column A in t1` and `all values of column B in t2`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer which explains _"Why"_ the answer you gave was a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM TableA
CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```